# Strange crash: NSRangeException with "unhelpful" stacktrace

Tags: ios, objective-c

So, this is one of those crashes that only seem to happen with other people, and that I only found out about thanks to Bugsnag.

```
NSRangeException: -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds
```

So far so good, just your run-of-the-mill fencepost error or somesuch, right? Except the stacktrace looks like:

```
[appname]:0x0006a399 • [appname]
[appname]:0x00089435 • [appname]
[appname]:0x002629cb • _ZNSt3__16vectorIiNS_9allocatorIiEEE21__push_back_slow_pathIiEEvOT_
[appname]:0x001802b5 • _ZNSt3__16vectorIN7gmscore4base10reffed_ptrINS1_6vector16GLBaseLabelBatchEEENS_9allocatorIS6_EEE26__swap_out_circular_bufferERNS_14__split_bufferIS6_RS8_EE
[appname]:0x0019d115 • _ZNSt3__16vectorIN7gmscore6vector4text15GlyphQuadVertexENS_9allocatorIS4_EEE21__push_back_slow_pathIRKS4_EEvOT_
[appname]:0x0004eb33 • [appname]
[appname]:0x0004eae8 • [appname]
```

So I have absolutely no idea where this is coming from, but it seems not to be generated directly by a `characterAtIndex:` call in my code (besides, there's only one such call in the whole app and it's well safeguarded). It seems to be a very core C function that's trying to read from a string where the index is out of bounds, but from this stacktrace I can't even start to figure out where that is. Any ideas?

Comment: No, C++; what Core Foundation is implemented in.

Comment: When you see strange stack traces, look for memory corruption.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight and for C++ :P

Comment: @trojanfoe there is little to no C++ in CF.

Comment: @bbum So, `_ZNSt3__16vectorIN7gmscore4base10reffed_ptrINS1_6vector16GLBaseLabelBatchEEENS_9allocatorIS6_EEE26__swap_out_circular_bufferERNS_14__split_bufferIS6_RS8_E` is a C function name? It doesn't even remotely resemble to a mangled C++ member function, right?

Comment: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.19/

Comment: Anyway, you'll need to symbolicate that stacktrace in order to find out where in your code that crash was initiated. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/instruments_help-symbolication-help/ResymbolicationHelp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011398-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1

Comment: @trojanfoe he can't symbolicate it, it is missing nearly all information that is need to do that. Looking at the source of bugsnag at https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-ios/blob/master/Bugsnag%20Plugin/Bugsnag.m#L43 shows that this is clearly not useful :( The stack trace is useless and possibly misleading too. Get the crash report from the device or a proper crash reporting SDK that handles things the right way. This is not.

Comment: @Kerni All he needs are addresses, which he has.

Comment: Perhaps show the code where this exception is believed to originate.  Better to have the community take a look for themselves and maybe a logic issue will be spotted.

Comment: @trojanfoe Sorry, this is wrong. You need at least the loading address and the UUID of each binary in the stacktrace to symbolicate against the right dSYM. In addition the lib is not async safe at all, which will lead to invalid data in case of memory corruption etc.

Comment: @Kerni I disagree; I've written scripts to use `atos` to symbolicate from my own custom log files.

Comment: @trojanfoe The binary offset at which the images are loaded must be applied to the backtrace PC values to find the actual on-disk PC address; without that, there's no way to determine what the actual code was. On top of that, you need to know the source binary / dSYM against which to perform symbolication, which means you need a UUID (or at least a unique version number).

Comment: @H2CO3 That is a C++ symbol from the BOOST library. It isn't from CoreFoundation because CF does not use C++ (I just looked.   As far as this crash is concerned, it is likely that the backtrace is a red herring;  the location is different and the stack is potentially smashed.  I'd look for commonalities across crash reports -- same kind of device? Same OS version? Jailbroken?

Comment: @bbum Well, then not in CF, but C++ *is* definitely involved. (And right, it's still mostly irrelevant, just saying.)

Answer (score 4):

It may be that you are making a call to a system method that in turn calls to objectAtIndex:. I tend to always have an exception breakpoint on in the project while debugging, so it will then show you the calling code that caused the exception.

To create one:

1. Open the breakpoints pane.
2. Create a new breakpoint at the bottom of the pane

[image]

3. Choose "Add Exception Breakpoint..."
4. On the next screen leave the default options and click "Done"

[image]

Cause the crash again and see where it breaks you app.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The OP has stated that it's only crashing on someone else's device (i.e. a customer) not on his dev kit.

Comment: Trojan is right, but I'll give credit for a well written response.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Missed that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post a full crash report?  There may be other clues.

Given the exception + stack trace, I suspect that there is stack corruption at play or that there is something goofy with the configuration of exception handlers that are causing the stack to be misreported (both of which I've seen before).

If you have a collection of crash reports, then check for commonalities between them;

- all on the same model of device?
- ... same release of OS?
- jailbroken?

... etc ...

Bugs like these are maddening to figure out, generally.

Comment: good call - all (4) reports are running iOS Version 6.1.4 (Build 10B350) on iPhone 5. Should I be searching for documented instabilities on that device/OS combination? However, if the stacktrace is a red herring, it's a pretty constant one -- exactly the same on all 4 reports.

Comment: As it turns out, 3 of the four crashes happened to the same user, within a 3-minute window. He was logged into my back-end, so I'm going to find his number and give him a call. Will be sure to let you know if I can extract useful info. :)

Comment: There ya go!  Most of these kinds of super-wonky crashes that occur in low frequency will be clustered around a very specific configuration or user.  Never underestimate a user's power to baffle you with their behavior. http://xkcd.com/327/